# Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS Install/Boot Lockup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, upgrade, freeze

I have an Asus Laptop that I am interested in dual-booting to Ubuntu Server 18.04.6 LTS.  I have installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS on a number of other laptops without issue.  However, this one locks up when I try to complete the install.  To get around this I installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS without issue and performed a 'do-release-upgrade' only to discover that the same issue presents on bootup.  It makes it about 2.8s into bootup and then freezes.  There are a number of 'log' messages on the screen but none that appeared to direct me to the root cause.  I have to hold the power button down to try another reboot.  If I boot up on the old kernel (Linux 4.4.0-210-generic) it boots normally.  If I try to boot up on the new kernel (Linux 4.15.0-184-generic) it locks up.  I would appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Based on a review of numerous online articles, I tried specifying the following kernel parameter combinations without any luck:

```
acpi_osi=Linux
quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 acpi_osi=Linux i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 idle=nomwait
acpi_osi=!
nouveau.modeset=0
quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0 acpi_osi=Linux
nomodeset
nouveau.noaccel=1
noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll
modprobe.blacklist=nouveau
nouveau.runpm=0
acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"
debug
pcie_aspm=off
earlyprintk=vga,keep
acpi.debug_layer=0x2 acpi.debug_level=0xffffffff
apic=debug
apic=debug show_lapic=all
csdlock_debug=ext
debug_objects
debugpat
dma_debug=on
dyndbg
efi=debug
keep_bootcon
i8042.debug
ignore_loglevel
initcall_debug
loglevel=7
lsm.debug
memblock=debug
nfsrootdebug
no_console_suspend
ohci1394_dma=early
pm_debug_messages
print-fatal-signals=on
rockchip.usb_uart
sysrq_always_enabled
udbg-immortal
xmon=early
video=SVIDEO-1:d
video=VGA-1:1280x800
i915.enable_execlists=0
intel_idle.max_cstate=1
video=SVIDEO-1:d
video=VGA-1:1280x800
i915.enable_execlists=0
intel_idle.max_cstate=1
```

After booting into the old kernel I checked the logs and there are no logs for the failed boot attempts.  journalctl lists out the previous boot attempts but they are all for those boot attempts on the old kernel (i.e. that were successful).

Thanks!

Comment: Please check your details; Ubuntu 18.04.7 doesn't exist, so you likely mean off-topic Ubuntu 16.04.7 which is EOSS & thus off-topic here.  As I understand your question you're trying to use 18.04 (*thus on-topic*); and if *release-upgrading* from 16.04 I'd have had both kernel stacks installed (GA & HWE) so your upgraded system gave you choices of 4.15 & 5.4 given you seem to have kernel issues. You also gave no details on what kernel changes you attempted; if you tried runlevel 1 etc, nor details of any message(s) you see, nor if you booted *live* media & could see any details in logs etc.

Comment: Thanks guiverc.  I corrected the Ubuntu Server version in the title, and added the kernel changes that I attempted.  I set kernel parameter 'single' to boot into single user mode but the result was another lockup on boot at the same place on the console.  I initially tried installing from live media and that was when I first encountered the lockup issue.

Comment: basic stuff:  did you verify the ISO before writing to media? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) then verify write to media? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck which applies more to desktop ISOs; sorry I can't recall how it was done on 18.04 server ISOs & thus the link for verification of ISO write to media; I'm a desktop user mostly).  I noted update; I left prior message as it mentioned GA/HWE kernel stack where an upgrade from 16.04 (4.4 & 4.15) would result in 18.04 having 4.15 & 5.4 kernel options giving two kernel stacks

Comment: As stated in my first comment; I'd also boot *live* media so you could explore logs on the server that may reveal where it's stopping boot. The trying *single* (runlevel 1) is a key point to me, but that highlights I'd be checking your ISO or write to media first..  then checking hardware to ensure RAM is good, PSU good etc as it screams issue with procedure (ISO) or hardware to me. I did encounter (in QA for desktop systems) issues with 5.3 & 5.4 kernel on some *very* old laptops but don't recall any with 4.15 kernel.

Comment: I have confirmed that my ISO is good (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and after re-writing to USB I verified write to media was successful (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck). There are similar capabilities for the Ubuntu server install.  I burned the .iso to USB using Rufus and accepted the defaults.  Slightly different result:  when I select "Install Ubuntu" from grub menu I just get a black screen with a non-blinking cursor in the top left corner. The system boots fine in Windows 8.1 and kernel Linux 4.4.0-210-generic.

Comment: The Ubuntu Server install media is 'live' but does not present the 'try ubuntu' option in the same way that I have seen for the desktop systems.  The install fails as previously described.  I have access to the logs when I boot into the old kernel, but as mentioned nothing shows up for the boot attempts that result in a lock-up.  I did notice that if I select "Boot and install with the HWE kernel" that the install progresses normally, and this site (https://ubuntu.com/kernel/lifecycle#installation-18-04) indicates that it runs on kernel v4.15 instead of v5.4+.